# Is It safe to use del for SqlAlchemy connection in python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

This is my code when I have used `self.engine.dispose()` It gives me Exception, so should i use this `del self.engine` it work fine, please give me any advice.

```
class MSSqlAlchemyConn(object):
def __init__(self, connection_obj):
    """
    Constructor for SQLAlchemy.
    """
    try:
        # connection string
        # example: mysql+mysqldb://[mysqluser]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[db_name]
        constr = "mssql+pymssql://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (connection_obj['USER'], connection_obj['PASSWORD'],
                                                  connection_obj['HOST'],
                                                  connection_obj['DATABASE'])
        self.engine = create_engine(constr, echo=False)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)

def __del__(self):
    if self.engine is not None:
        del self.engine
```

Comment: Why the need to `dispose()` or `del`? Are you sure you need to do either of those?

Comment: Your class name would hint at a slight misunderstanding as to what an engine is. An engine is – usually – an application wide global resource that exists throughout the app's lifetime, handling, pooling, and handing out connections: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#basic-usage. This custom class seems highly unusual.

Comment: so what should i do now @Ilja Everilä

Comment: @leovp if Im not `dispose()` or `del` then connection would be open need to destruct or not.

Comment: Well you could read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#engine-disposal. It specifically discourages trusting Python's garbage collection, if you happen to need manual disposal, which is not that common. Note that your `__del__` is just redundant. If and when an `MSSqlAlchemyConn` object is garbage collected, the engine will also lose its references, unless you've created references to it elsewhere, in which case your `del self.engine` wouldn't help either. `del` does not "delete" the object, but the name referring to it.

Comment: ok thanks @ Ilja Everilä. but I have create object like `self.alchemy_toyokeizai = MSSqlAlchemyConn(MSSQL_toyokeizai)`  and  i have also `del` this object.